# Python 3.9 quandl NoModuleFound (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, quandl

I am using Python3.9 on Windows machine. I created a virtual environment (my_venv) and activated it. cd to the my_venv folder and then did `pip3 install quandl` if I then run `pip3 list` I can see Quandl3.7.0 in the list.

making sure I am in the my_venv directory I then run Jupyter Notebook and it launches and says the kernel is called python3 (which is the only kernel available). When I then run import quandl I get "No Module named 'quandl'"

Note: I have tried the import with and without a capital Q and in both cases it gives the same error.

Comment: If [this is the one you want](https://pypi.org/project/Quandl/), try in a cell in the notebook where you want to use, `%pip install Quandl` (**BETTER MAYBE? ==>** `%pip install quandl` since more of the documentation at https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python has lower case ). Then restart the kernel and try `import quandl` in the notebook.

Comment: @Wayne That seems to have resolved it! I'm confused what the actual issue was though?

Comment: You weren't installing into the environment that the notebook kernel uses. The magic command run from inside the notebook insures that happens. (Sometimes it is much easier than fussing about trying to determine the environment and install there from outside.) See about `%pip install` (and related `%conda install`) [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).